# pgf-plot node at the center-south of the image

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I use this code for drawing plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,samples=200]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-3:1.85] {1/(x-2) +3 };
    \addplot[blue,domain=2.15:6] {1/(x-2) + 3};
    \draw[red!20,dashed] (axis cs:2,-4) -- (axis cs:2,10);
    \end{axis}
    \node at (4.4,-0.6) {\ovalbox{one function}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want the node (e.g. `\ovalbox{one function}`) at the center of the image. I don't know how to do this automatically, so I do it as I assume it is right only by watching this. **Is it possible to put it at the center automatically?**
[image]

Comment: `\node at (current axis.center) {\ovalbox{one function}};`. You can also use `\node[draw,rounded corners] at (current axis.center) {one function};`, that way you do not need the ovalbox.

Comment: @marmot , thanks for your answer! I meant "center at the bottom of the image". Your code puts the *"one function"* inside the image (https://ibb.co/k20ff43). If I replace `center` with `north` the *"one function"* is at the right place, but a part of the picture is missing (https://ibb.co/H7Y3zsC).

Comment: Then use `\node at (current axis.south) {\ovalbox{one function}};` or `\node[draw,rounded corners] at (current axis.south) {one function};` after `\end{axis}`, or with `south` replaced by `north`. You can also use `clip=false` and put the node within the axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image defines a bounding box, just place the text to the south of this bounding box.

I anchor it to the north so that the text does not overlap the image.

```
\node[anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south) {\ovalbox{one function}};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,samples=200]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-3:1.85] {1/(x-2) +3 };
    \addplot[blue,domain=2.15:6] {1/(x-2) + 3};
    \draw[red!20,dashed] (axis cs:2,-4) -- (axis cs:2,10);
    \end{axis}
    \node[anchor=north] at (current bounding box.south) {\ovalbox{one function}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Voting down deserves an explanation. Without explanation this has no meaning other than gratuitous hostility.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,samples=200]
    \addplot[blue,domain=-3:1.85] {1/(x-2) +3 };
    \addplot[blue,domain=2.15:6] {1/(x-2) + 3};
    \draw[red!20,dashed] (axis cs:2,-4) -- (axis cs:2,10);
    \end{axis}
    \node[draw,rounded corners,below=1pt] at (current axis.south) {one function};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your solution works fine with the code I wrote here, but not with this in my book (https://ibb.co/yRP4GkK). So I accept ANdreC's (https://ibb.co/CWkqFXk).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using plain TikZ for plotting ordinary functions, to get the best picture as you like, in particular, adding some node at the center south of the current picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.4,xscale=.7]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(6,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,10) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue,smooth,samples=200] 
plot[domain=-3:1.85] (\x,{1/(\x-2)+3})
plot[domain=2.15:6] (\x,{1/(\x-2)+3});
\draw[red,dashed] (2,-4)--(2,10) (-3,3)--(6,3);
\path
(0,0) node[below left]{O}
(4.5,5) node[blue]{$y=3+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$}
(0,2.5) node[scale=.7,blue,below left]{$5/2$}
(5/3,0) node[scale=.7,blue,below left]{$5/3$}
(2,0) node[red,below right]{$2$}
(0,3) node[red,above left]{$3$};

\path (current bounding box.south) 
node[below=5mm,draw,rounded corners]
{a function with two asymptotes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: I know that pgfplots very useful (`colormap`, `quiver`, etc), but it make us loss of controls, or difficult to control. I will use `pgfplots` if plain TikZ is too long to draw.

For the answers using `pgfplots` here:

- Should numbers -2,2,4,6,8 appear? Someone may say: "we can control appearance by adding some options inside `axis` environment", but it is not convernient. Moreover, numbers 5/2, 5/3 should be appear.
- I put options `[yscale=.4,xscale=.7]` to make plain TikZ figure is almost same size with `pgfplots` figure. So `pgfplots` automatically scaled the figure. Sometimes this is good, sometimes it is not.
- Removing option `[axis lines=middle]`, appearance of the figure is totally changed. How would we want numbers `5.10.15` with big box around?

[image]

I put all code together for comparing.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=200]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:1.85] {1/(x-2) +3 };
\addplot[blue,domain=2.15:6] {1/(x-2) + 3};
\draw[red] (axis cs:2,-4) -- (axis cs:2,10);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,samples=200]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:1.85] {1/(x-2) +3 };
\addplot[blue,domain=2.15:6] {1/(x-2) + 3};
\draw[red!20,dashed] (axis cs:2,-4) -- (axis cs:2,10);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.4,xscale=.7]
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(6,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,10) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[blue,smooth,samples=200] 
plot[domain=-3:1.85] (\x,{1/(\x-2)+3})
plot[domain=2.15:6] (\x,{1/(\x-2)+3});
\draw[red,dashed] (2,-4)--(2,10) (-3,3)--(6,3);
\path
(0,0) node[below left]{O}
(4.5,5) node[blue]{$y=3+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$}
(0,2.5) node[scale=.7,blue,below left]{$5/2$}
(5/3,0) node[scale=.7,blue,below left]{$5/3$}
(2,0) node[red,below right]{$2$}
(0,3) node[red,above left]{$3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```